# If inside each in handlebars.js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I would like to be able to do below with Handlebars.js, but it's not working?

```
   {{#each questions}}
     <p>{{content}}</p> 
     {{#if user}} display reply button {/if}
   {{/each}}
```

I want to display all questions and if the user is logged in he can reply.

here is my nodejs code

```
router.get('/question', function(req, res){
  Question.find({}).then (questions =>{
    res.render('question',{questions});
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Is `questions[0].user` a valid property in this example? And what do you mean by "not working"? It errors? It just never shows "display reply button"? Something else?

Comment: I don't think so. when I put "{{#if user}} display reply button {/if}" outside each statement, the button displayed. But I want to display reply button under each question

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths

Comment: I alreday saw that. still facing the pb.

Answer (score 1):

If inside each in handlebars.js,  then you  need to use `**/`  **(`**/user`)**

try like this ,

```
 {{#each questions}}
     <p>{{content}}</p> 
     {{#if ../user}} display reply button {/if}
   {{/each}}
```